# How to build a presentaion page for all the articles in specific category in Joomla?

Tags: list, joomla, content-management-system, presentation, article

This is what I have in mind:

[image: example]

Can anyone point out some relevant resources?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would look into installing a module [such as these](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/news-display/articles-display/articles-listing) that would create a menu based on category or section and sit on the side of your articles. Some of the modules provide good features and options, and you can find them for 1.5-2.5.

This module is very flexible and would easily accomplish your goal: [DM Article List Pro](http://dmjoomlaextensions.com/pro-extensions/joomla-modules/dm-article-titles-list-pro.html)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I had a look at that category of extensions but ... I would really appreciate a suggestion/recommendation with respect to my desired outcome.

Comment: Could you give some clarification on what the modules lack in your desired outcome? I've updated my answer with a specific module that seems to fit your needs.

Comment: Hey, thanks. The module has a big disadvantage: it's not free (although there is a free limited version). Nevertheless, it doesn't offer a solution when it comes to the main region (the one that should display the content of the selected article).

Comment: [QuickViewer](http://www.windowswipers.com/exchange/module-demos.html?&currentparams=&currentmodule=mod_quickviewer) is nice but is has two flaws: the layout is different (everything is horizontal) and it's only for Joomla 1.5 (I'm using 2.5).

Comment: @Yeseanul I've used that module and it does what you want to achieve. The popup can be disabled.

Comment: @Shaz You're talking about the Pro payed version of DM Article List, or the free one?

Comment: I ended up using [QuickViewer](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/news-display/articles-display/articles-listing/17341).